# How to extract the first character from strings with specific patterns

Tags: r, regex

I would like to extract the first number which follows a pattern( here it is `*`)

```
c(" 2 X[0,JOHNSON] * 0 0 1 ", 
  " 3 X[0,WILLIAMS]", 
  " * 1 0 1 ", 
  " 4 X[0,JONES] * 0 0 1 " )
```

here I am looking for `(0,NA,1,0)`

How can I do this in R?

Comment: thats a new string altogether !!

Comment: @joel.wilson how to extract the first number in every alternate line/character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first using `%%2` to extract the even position elements, then remove all white spaces, followed by `substr` that just extracts the first character of each string

```
substr(gsub(" ", "", x[seq_along(x)%%2==0]),1,1)
# [1] "0" "1" "0" "1"

as.numeric(substr(gsub(" ", "", x[seq_along(x)%%2==0]),1,1))
# [1] 0 1 0 1

library(stringr)
s <- str_extract(x, "\\* *\\d")  # looking for this pattern.
substr(s, nchar(s), nchar(s))
# [1] "0" NA  "1" "0"
```

Incase you find it difficult to understand regex : `\\*` means to search for `*`, `*` means to search for 0 or more spaces between `*` and a digit `\\d`

Comment: I have accepted your answer. However, I have another almost similar character vector, but this time there is no such pattern as in even positioned string. The vector is
c("     2 X[0,JOHNSON] *              0             0             1 ", 
"     3 X[0,WILLIAMS]", "                    *              1             0             1 ", 
"     4 X[0,JONES]   *              0             0             1 "
)

here I am looking for (0,NA,1,0)

The larger vector has random missing * in between.

Comment: @darkage i had edited my answer, hope that works for you

Answer (score 0):

We can use `grep` with `substr`

```
as.integer(substr(trimws(v1[!grepl("\\[", v1)]),1, 1))
#[1] 0 1 0 1
```

#### Update

For the new example in OP's post

```
as.integer(sub(".*(?<=[*])\\s*(\\d+).*", "\\1", v2, perl = TRUE))
#[1]  0 NA  1  0
```